# Flutter end of ListView from data in Firestore

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to add some empty tiles to the bottom of my listview so that I can put "See More" button on that part. The data I'm displaying on the screen is from Firebase. This is something I learned from YouTube tutorials. This is my code.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Collection.limit(10).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return !snapshot.hasData
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Card(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(document['title']),
                        subtitle: Text(document['body']),
                        onTap: () async { },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Some people have already advised me to use ListView.builder, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code. I repeatedly tried to use ListView.Builder but failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Collection.limit(10).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Center(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text("some text"),
                          subtitle: Text("some text"),
                          onTap: () async {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("See More"))
                    ],
                  )));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello what if I want to load the title from the collection? how do i do that? I updated the code that I posted.

Comment: you can use snapshot.data.title or which property your class has

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work for me